# how can I speed up gsutil transfers of large files?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I use the gsutils command to download large files from Google Cloud Storage. How can I speed up the transfer?

Answer (score 3):

Use gcloud storage. E.g. instead of

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/file .
```

use

```
gcloud storage cp gs://bucket/file .
```

This is up to 94% faster according to https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/new-gcloud-storage-cli-for-your-data-transfers